# Query SIM PIN status with `nmcli`

Tags: modem, nmcli

I am working with `nmcli` to create a modem connection using a SIM.

I need to know: is there a command (possibily, a `nmcli` command) that queries the SIM and returns an answer that tells whether the PIN is enabled or not on that SIM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `mmcli`.

Get modem index using:

```
$ mmcli -L
    Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E176
```

and then get the modem info (including SIM info) using:

```
$ sudo mmcli -m 0
...
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'sim-pin'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3), sim-puk (10)'
           |          state: 'locked'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'unknown'
           | signal quality: '0' (cached)
  -------------------------
...
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0'
...
```

See [link](https://core.docs.ubuntu.com/en/stacks/network/modem-manager/docs/entering-sim-passwords)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I assume that the `lock` and the `state` are telling me what I want to know.

Comment: Use `-K` with `mmcli` to run any action with "machine-friendly key-value output" (or -J for JSON). In bash you could read the state like this: `read -r key value < <(mmcli -K -m 1 | grep -F 'modem.generic.state' | sed -r -e 's/^([^ ]+)\s*:\s*(.*)$/\1 \2/g')`. Where `$key = "modem.generic.state"` and `$value = "locked"`.